# SQL command based on PHP strstr or LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Could somebody please offer some assistance. I have a standard SQL command as follows

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date > :FromDate AND Date < :EndDate";
```

This works fine but returns rows that are not relevant. I am having to make use of a php loop and go through them to filter out the desired records using an `if` statement.

```
$col1 = $col1["colVal"]

if(strstr($col1, "ABC") !== FALSE) {
    // can be used on page
}
```

Is there a way of doing this within the `sql` so I only return required results? I need it to check that the `col` value string only contains the first letters as `ABC`. Would the following `sql` work?

```
$string = "ABC";

$SQL = "
SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE 
    Date > :FromDate 
    AND Date < :EndDate 
    AND col1 LIKE $string
";
```

Comment: Would it work? Well, let me ask back, what happens when you try?

Comment: @hakre I haven't got access until tomorrow. I was on it today and I'm searching for a solution tonight ready to try again tomorrow.

Comment: which database client library are you using? (I just ask to show you the better ones of the duplicates we have on site about it)

Comment: Please be **extremely** careful to use parameters for any and all data. You've got `$string` here unescaped which is very worrying.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, the string is personally set by me on the script. There are no `POST` or `REQUESTS` running on the rest of this script, so in theory shouldn't need escaping (deep gulp)

Comment: Don't take chances. Escape it. If it's not blindingly clear it's properly escaped you've got issues, and placeholders are the best way to present it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `strstr` in the same manner as `substr`, where the string contains `ABC`.

```
SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE Date > :FromDate
    AND Date < :EndDate
    AND col1 LIKE '%$string%';
```

If you want to search for a string where the first characters are `ABC`, use:

```
SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE Date > :FromDate
    AND Date < :EndDate
    AND col1 LIKE '$string%';
```

`stristr`, however, would be a different story altogether.

Comment: +1. Also he can use [MySQL BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: @Itay How would a `BETWEEN` clause work on a string/substring?

Comment: *Every* value here should be parameterized including the `$string` one.

Comment: I was talking about this part `Date > :FromDate AND Date < :EndDate`

Comment: Thanks a lot for every bodies help

Comment: @Itay I see, but then the logic changes. I believe `BETWEEN` is equivalent to `>=` to `<=`, whereas here it is `>` to `<`. Maybe it's negligible in OP's case, maybe not.